# I met an matplotlib backend error just after Spyder launched

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

Today when I launched my Spyder the IPython console immediately showed me a note:

> raise ValueError(f"Key {key}: {ve}") from None
> ValueError: Key backend: 'qt4agg' is not a valid value for backend; supported values are ['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'GTK4Agg', 'GTK4Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'QtAgg', 'QtCairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']

I tried to update matplotlib in anaconda command line, but after the updating it still appeared. How can I cope with this problem?

Comment: Does [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) help to configure your backend appropriately?

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks for the link. I ran into a more serious trouble: I tried to change the backend in Tools\preference\IPython console\Graphic\backend, and then selected Tkinter, after applying to the current kernal, I can't reconnect to the kernal, and then the failure recurs every time when I lunch the Spyder, It is completely paralyzed..

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a bug in Spyder because we still offer the possibility to set the Qt4 backend, but Matplotlib removed it some versions ago. So please change your backend to other value.

We'll fix this problem in our 5.3.0 version, to be released in March 2022, by removing that option.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But now I am in trouble after trying to change the backend in Tools\Preference\IPython console\graphic\backend and choose {Tkinter}, after that changing, I cant connect to the kernal, neither change the backend anymore. It seems that my Spyder has been completely disabled.

Comment: The `Tkinter` backend has some issues that will be fixed in our next version (5.2.2), to be released next week. For now switch to `Automatic` (if you're using 5.2.1) or `Inline` (if you're using an older version).

Comment: That works! Thank you!